# Count number of records by year between two ranges in excel and dealing with null dates

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have an Excel table with information about different local business including the date when they started their operations and the date of business close. You can see a simplified version below:

[image: My Excel table]

What I need is to count the number of business in activity in each year, which means:

- The business must have started their operations (*startdate* column) before or in the current year.
- The business must have ended their operations (*enddate* column) after the current year.
- If a business is still active (meaning that the *enddate* column is null or " - - "), it still counts in the current year.

I want to put the counts in the F column, beginning in the year 1973 until 2020.

For example: for the year **1990** the number of business is **7**:

- ABC: stardate before 1990 and enddate null
- GHI: stardate before 1990 and enddate null
- JKL: stardate before 1990 and enddate null
- MNO: stardate before 1990 and enddate after 1990
- PQR: stardate before 1990 and enddate after 1990
- STU: stardate before 1990 and enddate after 1990
- VW: stardate in 1990 (before the end of the year) and enddate after 1990

Comment: Do you want a PowerQuery solution?

Comment: @AnilGoyal No, just a simple excel formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following array formula:

```
=SUM((YEAR($B$2:$B$10)<=E2)*(YEAR(IF(ISNUMBER($C$2:$C$10),$C$2:$C$10,TODAY()))>E2))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting the same results: for 1973 is 0, for 1974 is 0, for 1975 is 1, and so on. Is there any special config you made for that formula? BTW, I'm translating all functions to their spanish equivalents.

Comment: @Juank Do you enter it as array formula?

Comment: It appears a set of parenthesis were the problem. Thank you very much, your answer really helped me.

Comment: @Juank Glad you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$10<=DATE(E2,1,1))*(IF(ISNUMBER($C$:$C$10),$C$:$C$10,TODAY())>=DATE(E2,12,31)))
```

Comment: I'm getting 0 for all years. Also, in the ISNUMBER formula had to correct the range to $C$2:$C$10 because excel throw an error.

Comment: Then there is a chance your dates are text that looks like dates and not true dates.

Comment: The cell data type says those are Dates (not numbers, general, or other type). IS there another way to check if those values are true dates?